# Is there an "approved" icon for jump/back five seconds?

Tags: icons

In media players like vlc, we have the option of *"jumping" forward and back by a few seconds*, a feature I'v always loved.

Which icon would you use to display this option, like the triangle for "play" and the double bars for "pause" ?

Comment: The Kindle Fire's video player has a...something, that represents this action...

Comment: Icon request questions are [off topic](http://ux.stackexchange.com/faq#im-having-trouble-coming-up-with-a-good-icon-for-feature-x-should-i-ask-here-for-ideas)

Comment: @ChrisF if so, this should be migrated to graphicdesign.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @DannyVarod - flag the question for one of the moderators to check with GD.

Comment: @ChrisF I would if I was sure it is off-topic. This does seem more like a UX issue then a design issue to me. I just meant, that migrating would be a better option than closing.

Comment: Seemed more about UX than design, yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've seen a circular, anti-clockwise arrow (much like the refresh button on browsers) with the # of seconds inside the circle, but I'm not entirely convinced it's a good idea... my first thought on seeing it was "Refresh 15? What does that mean?"

Comment: If it were a semi-circular arrow that'd be pretty good actually. The arrow would explicitly be skipping over 15 seconds.

Comment: @JustinPiper or returning to 15 something.

Answer (score 2):

I think double triangles means something like that (◀◀ and ▶▶)

Please do not forget to add tooltip explaining what exactly does these buttons do.

Answer (score 1):

I think Tivo popularized this function. Their remote used ⇤ (U+21E4 LEFTWARDS ARROW TO BAR) and ⇥ (U+21E5 RIGHTWARDS ARROW TO BAR).

Answer (score 1):

Double triangles (at Nikita showed) usually mean rewind/fast-forward.
A long click on them usually rewinds/fast-forwards until click ends.

Double triangles with a line at end of arrow e.g. |<< or >>| usually mean jump to prev/next track.

If both types of buttons are present (e.g. |<< and <<) then a brief click on "<<"  usually jumps backward/forward a constant amount of time (e.g. 10 seconds).

If only one type of button is present - the double triangles then a brief click on "<<" or ">>" may act like "|<<" and ">>|".

If you want the action of the button to be clear try double arrows with the time specified on it e.g. "<<5sec" and ">>5sec".
Then 5sec could be at the bottom of the button under the "<<" or ">>" picture.

Edit:
I just recalled seeing icons with one triangle and a line (e.g. "|<" and ">|") in an icon package and using them for a similar purpose. I think that having one triangle instead of two could help differ from rewind/fast-forward.